# How can I help talk a close friend out of religiously radicalizing?

Tags: friends, socializing, religion, mental-health, anxiety

I have a close friend that I grew up with that has begun to show signs of radicalizing in his religion. I do not share this religion but we are close friends. He has many friends, very educated, a steady girlfriend, and is generally well liked. I am used to helping people with depression, but this is new for me.

I feel that this might be something that I will encounter for the rest of my life, so I would like to prepare more for it.

#### How might I go through the process of talking him through this?

At the core, I feel that this stems from unresolved anxiety. So I was planning on forming my approach on this. I see having an open discussion as a way of starting the process of talking him out of it.

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me what your goal is. Your question appears to be about "talking him through this," but what does that mean? Are you trying to talk him *out* of this? Or trying to have an open discussion about his motives and beliefs?

Comment: I guess I saw having an open discussion as a way of starting the process of talking him out of it. I would like to talk him out of it

Comment: Hi Gabriel, welcome to IPS! I edited a bit to make it more on-topic - StackExchange isn't a good format for getting a list of resources, and "Is this a good idea" is somewhat opinion-based. It would also help to get some more info about how your friend talks about this stuff, have you tried having an open discussion with him before, if so how did he respond? Or if not, could you be more specific about why you're worried about bringing it up (the approach might be different if you're worried he'll respond angrily vs. change subject, for example)?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "radicalizing in his religion?" Is there something about his practice of religion that you feel would be harmful to himself or to others?

Comment: Hey, could you add more details as to what is the link between your question and mental-health/anxiety? Does your friend suffer a severe form of anxiety? And are you afraid that this might impact the way you should talk to him?